# How could I populate data from codebehind to ascx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

In my codebehind I get the company names and addresses as:

```
connection.Open();
                    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
                    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();


                    sqlReader.Read();
                    dt.Load(sqlReader);
                    for(int i>=0 ; i = dt.Rows.Cout - 1; i--)
                    {
                           string companyName[i] = dt.Rows[i]["companyName"].ToString();
                           sqlCmd.CommandText = addr;
                           sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyName", dt.Rows[i]["companyName"].ToString());

                           using (var addressReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                           {
                               if (addressReader.Read())
                               {
                                string address[i] = addressReader["address"].ToString();
                               }
                           }
                     }
```

So I want to put companyName[i] and address[i] values in my ascx file. Current it use datagrid dgcompanies, but I don't want to use datagrid, just want to reuse it current table format:

```
<table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
<tr id="resultsRow" runat="server">
    <td vAlign="top">
        <a name="tagCompaniesDatagrid"></a>
        <asp:datagrid id="dgCompanies" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyField="companyId" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowPaging="True" AllowCustomPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanged="dgCompanies_Paging" Runat="server" onprerender="dgCompanies_PreRender" >
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="DGColumnHead" />
            <ItemStyle CssClass="DGItemStyle" />
            <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="DGAlternatingItemStyle" />
            <FooterStyle CssClass="DGColumnFoot" />
            <PagerStyle CssClass="DGPagerStyle" HorizontalAlign="Right" Mode="NumericPages" PageButtonCount="5" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="companyName" HeaderText="Company Name">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="40%" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="95%">
                                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="LinkButton" id="btnView" Runat="server" CommandName="ViewDetails" CommandArgument="<%# GetViewUrl((System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)Container.DataItem) %>">
                                        <span ID="SpanTitle" Runat="server">
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"companyName") %>
                                        </span>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:Label CssClass="DGNormal" ID="lblStatus" Runat="server" text='<%# StatusToText((int) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"statusId")) %>'/>
                                    <asp:Image visible='<%# (bool) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"WMCCMRated") %>' ID="imgProfiled" Runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/WMCCMRated.gif" AlternateText="This company has been competency profiled by WMG" />
                                    <asp:Image Visible='<%# !(Convert.IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"feedback")))%>' ID="feedback" Runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/feedback.gif" AlternateText="The number of feedback this company has been received is ->" ImageAlign="Bottom" Height="18px" Width="12px"/>
                                    <asp:Label CssClass="NormalBold" ID="lblFeedback" Runat="server" text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"feedback") %>' ForeColor="Navy"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="DGNormalBold">
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"phoneNumber") %>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="DGNormal" ID="SpanProfile" Runat="server">
                                        <%# cutToNCharacters((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Profile")) %>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <cc1:DropDownCombo ID="dplCompanies" Runat="server" Width="95%" DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField="CompanyId" DataSource='<%# GetCompanyNames() %>' />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="address" HeaderText="Address">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="15%" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="DGNormal" ID="SpanAddress" Runat="server">
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"address")%>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

My understanding is, I should replace these two lines:

```
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"companyName") %>
```

and

```
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"address")%>
```

But I don't know what else I need to change and how to make it automatically populate for my set of values. Any one familiar with this ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing here... why are you doing this `string address[i] = addressReader["address"].ToString();`? It makes no sense since you are creating and array of `i` dimension that never get used... your data is going nowhere...

Comment: follow on... can you provide a short example of what is rendered in the browser and also what you expect to be rendered.

Comment: My data will go to display at ascx file as mentioned in the question!

Comment: I do get that, but the line I mentioned does not do anything. it does not do anything with the data that is read out. You need to declare the array's outside of the loops to be able to use them.

Comment: I really don't understand your idea. The array will be declare outside the loop first, then in the loop, I need to have that line to store the values to the array, I think it makes sense? Each time i change in the loop then the parameter add to commandText changes, then addressReader changes, then address[i] get new value...

Comment: If you want to set values to an already declared array you don't need to put the type identifier before it i.e.:`address[i] = addressReader["address"].ToString();`. address will already be declared somewhere outside with `string[] address = new string[SIZE_OF_ADDRESSES];`.

Comment: That is fine! Do you have any idea about my question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54731/discussion-between-michael-coxon-and-user1314404).

Answer (score 0):

After the chat this is what you need...

the data needs to be stored in a model and then can be 'echoed' out on to the page. You need to modify the model to your needs...

### ascx

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>company</td><td>address</td>
    </tr>
    <asp:Repeater ID="companyRepeater" runat="server">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Eval("companyName") %></td><td><%#Eval("address") %></td>
        </tr>
    </Itemtemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

### code behind

```
public class CompanyModel{
    public string companyName {get; set;}
    public string address {get; set;}
}

sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT companyName, address FROM company_table", connection);
SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

List<CompanyModel> companies= new List<CompanyModel>();
sqlReader.Read();
dt.Load(sqlReader);

for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    companies.Add(new CompanyModel 
    { 
        companyName =  dt.Rows[i]["companyName"].ToString(),
        address =  dt.Rows[i]["address"].ToString()
    });
}

companyRepeater.DataSource = companies;
companyRepeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: How could I access each companyName stored in the list to query other values and add them to CompanyModel ?

Comment: I am trying this: foreach(List<Component> compnName in companies.Contains("companyName")
 { sqlCmd.CommandText = getKey;sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyName", compnName); using (var keyReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())  { if (keyReader.Read()) {companies.Add(new CompanyModel compnKey =  keyReader.GetString("key")); } } sqlCmd.CommandText = getstandard; sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyName", compnName);using (var standardReader =sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()) { if (standardReader.Read()){ companies.Add(new CompanyModel compnStandards =  keyReader.GetString("standards")); } } }

Comment: The list contains companies. so you need to get the company out of it. `companies.Contains()` returns a bool. The code you provided probably will never compile as you are asking it to find a string in the list. You need `foreach(CompanyModel company in companies) { string companyName = company.companyName; }`

Comment: Please do some reading about iterating and data modelling as you are just going to confuse yourself if you don't understand the basics of iteration. A quick google gave me this.. http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Comment: Can I add more value to companies at different steps? Like : companies.Add(new CompanyModel {compnStandards = dtb2.Rows[0][0].ToString() }); Then do I need to assign datasource and databind to companyRepeater everytime ?

Comment: Looks like using this command I will loose old stored values in companies?